# CoreData: save changes only from one thread

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I use `CoreData` from two threads with separate `NSManagedObjectContext` for each thread and a shared `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`, as it's recommended in [this guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html). My goal is to commit only changes made by one thread when calling `[NSManagedObjectContext save]` from this thread. So in the following scenario:

```
th1: add obj1 // don't save
th2: add obj2
th2: save
quit app
open app once again
```

I want only `obj2` to be saved. Is it possible? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: It seems like that will work. Do you have a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `NSManagedObjectContext` know with thread run him originally and `performBlock` is the method to retrieve this information.

```
 [myManagedObjectContext performBlock:^{
                    //do your stuff here in managedObjectContext thread
                }];
```

Remember only that is a block.

So if you have like you said TWO ManagedObjectContext you should have no problem with managed it, becouse `performBlock` deal only with context not PS.